# What causes about the crash of String_fastSubstring or tgkill?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

We collected a lot of crashes on the Google Play console about native method of String_fastSubstring. Most crashes occur on Android 6.0 and 7.0.

What kind of string may cause this error?

/system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
/system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
/system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
/system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
/system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
/system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
/system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
/system/lib/libart.so(_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+194)
/system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL20String_fastSubstringEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectii+162)
/system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.String.fastSubstring+92)
/system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.String.substring+140)
/system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.regex.Pattern.fastSplit+542)
/system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.String.split+64)
/system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.String.split+40)
/system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.UUID.fromString+56)
/data/app/com.igg.android.wegamers-1/oat/arm/base.odex

Image on below Link:

[Android 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/064Ww.png)

[Android 7.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMPgL.png)